# Getting the value from the dropdownbox Event Reciever sharepoint 2010

Tags: visual-studio, dropdown, event-receivers

I have an event reciever for item adding.

I'm using:

```
dropdwnvalue = web.Lists[properties.ListId].Fields["Names"].InternalName;

string selectedValue = properties.AfterProperties[dropdwnvalue].ToString();
```

In selectedValue I'm able to get the index of the selected dropdownbox.  Is there any way to get the value "Bob" instead of the index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this](http://spblog.net/post/2011/07/06/Accessing-SharePoint-lookup-fields-values-in-item-receivers-some-pitfalls.aspx) my blog post, it describes your situation.
Shortly, in before-receivers you always get a lookup id only (for lookup fields). If you want to get other item field values from lookup list, you must get item by this id and then get all required values.

Comment: Hi Kai, i tried from that example but, i m gettting the error that the item does not exits it must have been deleted by another user ..this is my code ----dropdwnvalue = web.Lists[properties.ListId].Fields["Names"].InternalName;   var list = web.Lists["Demolist"];   if (int.TryParse(properties.AfterProperties[dropdwnvalue].ToString(), out id))
             {
               
                 var item = list.GetItemById(id); 
                 var categoryNo = item["Names"];
            }  I m getting the error at the line var item

Comment: If `Names` is a lookup field, from what list it gets data?

Comment: Excellent Kai, i followed your example..and was able to get the name!..Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In general you can get it by using `SPFieldLookupValue`:

```
SPFieldLookupValue YourLookup = new (SPFieldLookupValue(Properties.AfterProperties.LisItem["Your lookup"] as string);
```

In your case the code would become:

```
dropdwnvalue = web.Lists[properties.ListId].Fields["Names"].InternalName;
String lookupFieldStringValue = Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties[dropdwnvalue]);
SPFieldLookupValue lookupFieldValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(lookupFieldStringValue);
```

**Update**

```
int lookedUpItemID = lookupFieldValue.LookupId;
```

If you want to use both `LookupId` and `LookupValue` then you can use [SPFieldLookupValue constructor with two parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa543857.aspx)

Something like this:

```
SPFieldLookupValue(1,"Test");
```

Comment: Hi..when i debugged it ..it is showing the lookupId=13..but the lookUpValue is "" empty..